# How can I switch the firebase config environment while running the app without needing to rebuild the app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I am developing an app using Flutter.

I want to be able to switch the firebase config environment (`google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.Info`) right in the app without having to rebuild the app.

Is that possible? I was able to do it with an API call.

I can switch version firebase configuration during application runtime.